# Null-checker in Java

Tags: java, null-check

I saw the following line of code in a project :
if **(null != policyProDO.getSelected())**.
I have never seen null on the left of assignment operator.
I would rather write the above line of code as : **if (policyProDO.getSelected() != null)**.
What's really the difference between the two statements if any?

Comment: it is just about coding style, in terms of execution is exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

There is not exectly any difference but it is convention we write

```
if (policyProDO.getSelected() != null)
```

To make better **readability** and **understandability**.